# Django 2.2 Deleting any user in the admin interface raises this error

Tags: python, django

Here is the error in question:

> IntegrityError at /admin/accounts/user/
>
> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

I looked elsewhere and couldn't find any simple fix. This error I believe is because I've used a custom User model where I inherit from AbstractBaseUser because I want my website to not have usernames but instead users are identified primarily by their emails. I am at a beginner level for using Django as well as anything related to relational databases.

```
#src/accounts.models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import get_template


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name=None, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password) # change user password
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.is_active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email,full_name=None, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                full_name=full_name,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name=None, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                full_name=full_name,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True,
                is_admin=True
        )
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login 
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user non superuser
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser 
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' #username
    # USERNAME_FIELD and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] #['full_name'] #python manage.py createsuperuser

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class EmailActivation(models.Model):
   user            = models.ForeignKey(User, 
   blank=True,
   null=True, 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE
) # required on Django 2.0+ deletes child objects on_delete
  #the error must be caused by this
    email           = models.EmailField()
    key             = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    activated       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    forced_expired  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    expires         = models.IntegerField(default=7) # 7 Days
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def regenerate(self):
        self.key = None
        self.save()
        if self.key is not None:
            return True
        return False

    def send_activation(self):
        if not self.activated and not self.forced_expired:
            if self.key:
                base_url = getattr(settings, 'BASE_URL', '<my-domain>')
                key_path = self.key # use reverse
                path = "{base}{path}".format(base=base_url, path=key_path)
                context = {
                    'path': path,
                    'email': self.email
                }
                txt_ = get_template("registration/emails/verify.txt").render(context)
                html_ = get_template("registration/emails/verify.html").render(context)
                subject = '1-Click Email Verification'
                from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
                recipient_list = [self.email]
                sent_mail = send_mail(
                            subject,
                            txt_,
                            from_email,
                            recipient_list,
                            html_message=html_,
                            fail_silently=False,
                    )
                return sent_mail
        return False



def pre_save_email_activation(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.activated and not instance.forced_expired:
        if not instance.key:
            instance.key = unique_key_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_email_activation, sender=EmailActivation)


def post_save_user_create_reciever(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        obj = EmailActivation.objects.create(user=instance, email=instance.email)
        obj.send_activation()

post_save.connect(post_save_user_create_reciever, sender=User)

class GuestEmail(models.Model):
    email       = models.EmailField()
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

EDIT:
As per requested by Tom Carrick here is my full traceback:

```
> Environment:
>
>
>Request Method: POST
>Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/user/

>Django Version: 2.2.12
>Python Version: 3.6.9
>Installed Applications:
>['django.contrib.admin',
> 'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages',
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> 'storages',
> 'accounts',
> 'addresses',
> 'analytics',
> 'billing',
> 'carts',
> 'marketing',
> 'orders',
> 'products',
> 'search',
> 'tags']
>Installed Middleware:
>['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
>
>
>Traceback:
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
>  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
>  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
>The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct >cause of the following exception:
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>  34.             response = get_response(request)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>  115.                 response = >self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, >*callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
>  606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, >**kwargs)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, >**kwargs)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
>  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
>  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
>  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
>  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, >**kwargs)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
>  1727.                 response = self.response_action(request, >queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
>  1397.             response = func(self, request, queryset)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions.py" in delete_selected
>  40.             modeladmin.delete_queryset(request, queryset)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in delete_queryset
>  1098.         queryset.delete()
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in delete
>  711.         deleted, _rows_count = collector.delete()
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in delete
>  312.                 count = query.delete_batch(pk_list, self.using)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py" in delete_batch
>  41.             num_deleted += >self.do_query(self.get_meta().db_table, self.where, using=using)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py" in do_query
>  24.         cursor = self.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(CURSOR)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
>  1140.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
>  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
>  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, >many=False, executor=self._execute)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
>  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
>  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
>  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from >exc_value
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
>  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
>File "/home/ray/Dev/rxvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
>  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
>Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/accounts/user/
>Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
>
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Try using another model name, to differentiate from the default user model. To me your code looks right, but there could be something in your project history and migrations that created a faulty database constraint.

Comment: One thing, though. Your foreignkey has null and blank set to true. If you have CASCADE set that should not be possible. I would remove those, to avoid confusion. Could possibly be a problem too.

Comment: Tom, I have edited the post to include the full traceback. Though  I don't think I formatted it correctly.